# Android EditText Cursor is not available

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

Hello I am trying to do an application and it uses own keyboard view not the default.

In the search area (Edittext) i can't use the default cursor

I am working on an example of keyboardview which is available on

[Android-KeyboardView-Example](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example)

the source codes of activity

```
package it.anddev.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.animation.Animation;

import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    private View mTargetView;
    private Keyboard mKeyboard;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
        mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
        mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                showKeyboardWithAnimation();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
        mKeyboardView
                .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                        this));
    }

    private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
        if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                    .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.this,
                            R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
            mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Does keyboardview blocking that future or how can I enable that?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have no android:focusable="true" in your layout parameters. Please post your layout XML with the affected EditText fields.